# How to use [FindMeetingTimes] in the Graph API (SDK 5.35) from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

If you run a common sample.

1.GraphClient.Me.FindMeetingTimes, the error [/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.]

2.GraphClient.Users["id"].FindMeetingTimes, an [Invalid user address] error occurs.

The following is the result.

[FindMeetingTimes Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

When I run POST in Graph Explorer ([https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/microsoft.graph.findMeetingTimes](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D/microsoft.graph.findMeetingTimes)), the response comes back correctly, but when I try with the source output in Code snippets However, an error occurs when trying with the source output in Code snippets.

[sample code (VSCode)]

Azure Function .Net 6 (LTS)Isolated

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class HttpTrigger0
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HttpTrigger0(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HttpTrigger5>();
        }

        [Function("HttpTrigger0")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // Dummy Id
            var userId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#client-credentials-provider
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TENANT_ID");
            var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENT_ID");
            var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENT_SECRET");
            var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions  
            {  
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud  
            }; 
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
            var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Me.FindMeetingTimes.FindMeetingTimesPostRequestBody
            //var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.FindMeetingTimes.FindMeetingTimesPostRequestBody
            {
                Attendees = new List<AttendeeBase>
                {
                    new AttendeeBase
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Name = "User1",
                            Address = "user1@test.onmicrosoft.com",
                        },
                    },
                    new AttendeeBase
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Name = "User2",
                            Address = "user2@test.onmicrosoft.com",
                        },
                    },
                    new AttendeeBase
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Name = "User3",
                            Address = "user3@test.onmicrosoft.com",
                        },
                    },
                },
            };
            try {
                var result = await graphClient.Me.FindMeetingTimes.PostAsync(requestBody);
                //var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].FindMeetingTimes.PostAsync(requestBody);
                return new OkObjectResult(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("TRC:" + e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("ERR:" + e.Message);
                return new OkObjectResult(null);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include more details like the code you tried by editing your question?

Comment: The error occurs if you are using client credentials flow but the endpoint supports only Delegated flows like authorization code flow, interactive flow or username password flow.

Comment: Authentication is failing.  You need a token : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#access-tokens

Comment: Sample source added.
Do I also need API permissions etc. in Azure potral?

Comment: Your code uses **client credentials** flow that is not supported for fetching `FindMeetingTimes`. To resolve the error, switch to **delegated** flow like username password flow by granting API permission of **Delegated** type.

Comment: How should it be coded? 
Do you know of any sources or websites that can help?

Comment: You can refer this MS Document and modify your code accordingly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#usernamepassword-provider

Comment: Not if the account has multi-factor authentication for login?

Comment: UsernamePasswordCredential authentication failed: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access 'XX'.

Comment: Then you need to switch to interactive flow or authorization code flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#interactive-provider

Comment: authentication screen appears in the browser and  
<Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab.  >
but,an err has occurred   
<InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.>

Comment: Could you include `Authentication` tab details of your app registration? Need to check what platform you used for redirect URL and whether you enabled public client option or not?

Comment: I got **same errors** when I ran your code in my console app like this [/me_error](https://i.imgur.com/RiGatyN.png) and [/users_error](https://i.imgur.com/oYbx9a5.png). When I switch to interactive flow with redirect_URI in `Web` platform without enabling public client, I got [same error](https://i.imgur.com/ru7MtBc.png)

Comment: To **resolve** the error, enable [public client option](https://i.imgur.com/oRiaVIv.png) and remove redirect Uri from `Web` and add it in _Mobile and desktop application_ platform like [this](https://i.imgur.com/dTSSOIh.png).

Comment: Sridevi Thank you very much.
I did the settings as you showed me and [MeetingTimeSuggestions] came back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error occurred as you are using client credentials flow to retrieve *findMeetingTimes* which is **not supported**.

To **resolve** the error, you need to switch to **delegated** flows like interactive flow or authorization code flow.

In your app registration, grant `Calendars.Read.Shared` permission of **Delegated** type while using delegated flows.

[image]

If you prefer interactive flow, you need to add **redirect URI** in *Mobile and Desktop applications* platform like this:

[image]

Make sure to **enable public client** flows in your app registration while using interactive flow:

[image]

In my case, I ran below sample c# code in Console app to retrieve *findMeetingTimes* using **interactive flow**:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

// Dummy Id
var userId = "userId";

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantID";
var clientId = "appID";
var clientSecret = "secret";
var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Me.FindMeetingTimes.FindMeetingTimesPostRequestBody
//var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.FindMeetingTimes.FindMeetingTimesPostRequestBody
{
    Attendees = new List<AttendeeBase>
                {
                    new AttendeeBase
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Name = "User1",
                            Address = "user1@test.onmicrosoft.com",
                        },
                    },
                    new AttendeeBase
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Name = "User2",
                            Address = "user2@test.onmicrosoft.com",
                        },
                    },
                    new AttendeeBase
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Name = "User3",
                            Address = "user3@test.onmicrosoft.com",
                        },
                    },
                },
};

try
{
    var result = await graphClient.Me.FindMeetingTimes.PostAsync(requestBody);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Reference:**
[Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#interactive-provider)